# how to display child records from main page to another page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

i have two pages ,in first page two input values is there from one object.while entering two values then clicks the button need to move another page and need to display the child records based upon parent record.how to pass two input values in url parameter and how to fetch the those url parameters in another page and display the records.can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those inputs are bound to controller fields called `fieldOne` and `fieldTwo`, in the `action` of a button in the main page:

```
 public PageReference goToAnotherPage() {
     PageReference pr = Page.AnotherPage;
     pr.getParameters().put('one', String.valueOf(fieldOne));
     pr.getParameters().put('two', String.valueOf(fieldTwo));
     return pr;
 }
```

and in the constructor of the `AnotherPage` controller:

```
 public with sharing class AnotherPageController {
     public AnotherPageController() {
         String one = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('one');
         String two = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('two');
         // Use the values here or assign to fields
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative** - Is to use  Flows instead of using visualforce pages.
Reference Doc -https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=vpm_admin_flow_overview.htm&siteLang=en_US

Comment: @user if this ans solved your issue. the pls accept the ans and upvote. :)